# What kinds of commands can run with exec?

Tags: bash, shell, exec

What kinds of commands can run with `exec`? For example, executable files, builtin commands, shell script, compound commands (e.g. looping, conditional branching),  pipeline, command list, commands grouped by parentheses or braces, ...?

Because the parent shell exits upon the command run with `exec` finishes running, it is hard to tell if there is an error.

Comment: I suspect it's just executable files, including scripts.  `exec` replaces the current process with the first argument, so that must be something that could be a process I suspect.  Also, the parent shell does not actually exit when `exec` finishes, the parent shell ceases to exist when `exec` starts

Comment: By cease to exit, do you mean the parent process hasn't exit when exec starts? When will the parent shell exit?

Comment: No, the parent process is replaced by the target of the `exec`. It doesn't exit. It is replaced.

Comment: @roaima: when the command run with `exec` finishes running, does the parent/shell process exit?

Comment: « No, the parent process is replaced by the target of the exec. It doesn't exit because there is no parent process left. It has been replaced. » I don't know how to explain it more succinctly than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec` replaces the current shell executable by another **executable**, i.e. an external command, in the same process. Since there is no shell to execute anything, shell concepts such as aliases, functions, builtins, or compound commands cannot be invoked via `exec`. (The syntax doesn't allow compound commands anyway.)

The shell does not exit when the command run with `exec` finishes running. The shell *program* terminates when it runs `exec`, in the sense that its code stops running (but, once again, the *process* does not exit). The shell *process* keeps running the new program. When the executed program terminates, the parent of the process is notified as usual; it is up to it to react to any error.

Comment: Thanks. What is "the parent of the process"?