# reason for exec in wrapper scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, exec

I have seen wrapper script examples which in a nutshell are following:

```
#!/bin/bash

myprog=sleep
echo "This is the wrapper script, it will exec "$myprog""

exec "$myprog" "$@"
```

As seen above, they use `exec` to replace the newly created shell almost immediately with the `$myprog`. One could achieve the same without `exec`:

```
#!/bin/bash

myprog=sleep
echo "This is the wrapper script, it will exec "$myprog""

"$myprog" "$@"
```

In this last example, a new bash instance is started and then `$myprog` is started as a child process of the bash instance.

What are the benefits of the first approach?

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Also (on *this* site!): [Use case / practical example for the shell's `exec` builtin](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270929/23408).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using `exec` makes the wrapper more transparent, i.e. it makes it less likely that the user or application that calls the script needs to be aware that it's a relay that in turns launches the “real” program.

In particular, if the caller wants to kill the program, they'll just kill the process they just launched. If the wrapper script runs a child process, the caller would need to know that they should find out the child of the wrapper and kill that instead. The wrapper script could set a trap to relay some signals, but that wouldn't work with SIGSTOP or SIGKILL which can't be caught.

Calling `exec` also saves a bit of memory (and other resources such as PIDs etc.) since it there's no need to keep an extra shell around with nothing left to do.

If there are multiple wrappers, the problems add up (difficulty in finding the right process to kill, memory overhead, etc.).

Some shells (e.g. the Korn shell) automatically detect when a command is the last one and there's no active trap and put an implicit `exec`, but not all do (e.g. not bash).

Comment: Bash execs if there is only one command (and no traps). AFAIK this isn't documented.

Comment: @PaulDraper: can you somehow confirm this? A quote from source code perhaps? This would be huge!

Comment: @MestreLion you can confirm this by running `bash -c 'echo $$; sleep infinity'. Then inspect that pid and you'll see that it is now the sleep process.

Comment: yes, bash does this. the behavior is gated by the [`ONESHOT` define](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/config-top.h#L39-L41), which appeared in bash 2.0. [this is the relevant code](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/builtins/evalstring.c#L479C8-L513), the comment explains the necessary conditions for the implicit exec to happen. the actual code implementing these conditions is [here](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/builtins/evalstring.c#L87-L116).

Answer (score 12):

Finding no duplicates... refer to the [FreeBSD handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/dads-sh-exec.html), which gives a good enough reason:

> The **`exec`** statement replaces the shell process with the specified program. If **`exec`** is omitted, the shell process remains in memory while the program is executing, and ***needlessly consumes*** system resources.

which is essentially the reason explained to me quite a while back (by one of the porters), and is fairly well-known.