# How can I forward #! through a bash script to provide indirection

Tags: bash, shebang

Sorry if the question statement wasn't very clear.

I'd like to have a bash script that I can edit to change the behavior of a bunch of other scripts.

For instance--I have some groovy scripts. they can be run either with the groovy interpreter "groovy" or with a special runner called "groovyclient".  I might want to change which one runs it (Or do something completely different like compile them into Java class files and run them with Java)

So if I have an indirect script: /home/me/groovy/groovyrun, that is a shell script, it might look like this:

```
/usr/bin/groovy %*
```

or like this:

```
/home/me/groovy/groovyclient $*
```

I tried a #! line on the original scripts that looks like this:

```
#!/home/me/groovy/groovyrun
```

and quickly realized that bash wasn't being invoked so it had no idea what to do with groovyrun

I then tried:

```
#!/bin/bash /home/me/groovy/groovyrun
```

But now I think that the $*

That should run it but I believe it has issues with getting to the original argument list (The $* in the called script is probably wrong).

Now I'm fairly lost as far as how to do this and I figure it's probably a common pattern and I'm just not familiar enough with Linux to know it (or even know how to find it), so I ask.

I could easily solve it if I forgo the #! altogether and just pass the groovy script to a shell script directly, but what fun is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you specify the shebang in your `groovyrun` script.

As a quick experiment, create `shell1` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
echo shell1: "$@"
sh "$@"
```

and `shell2` containing

```
#!/.../shell1
echo shell2: "$@"
```

(with the correct path to `shell1`); running `shell2 Hello` then produces

```
shell1: ./shell2 Hello
shell2: Hello
```

As you can see, the parameters passed to each script look correct in both cases.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed that--too simple?

Comment: As a follow up, is there any way to make the path to the second script relative to the directory of the first script? #!../groovyrun in the first script seems to be relative to the directory from which you launch the first script.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a level of indirection, where the program that you specify through a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang%20(Unix)) in a script is itself a script with a shebang. [Linux accepts nested shebangs, but other Unix variants don't](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#nesting). So you can put

```
#!/home/me/groovy/groovyrun
```

at the top of your Groovy scripts and

```
#!/bin/sh
```

at the top of `/home/me/groovy/groovyrun`.

To execute `groovyclient` or `groovy` from the wrapper script, use something like

```
#!/bin/sh
if …; then
  exec groovyclient "$@"
else
  exec groovy "$@"
fi
```

`"$@"` stands for the list of parameters passed to the script, copied exactly as they are (correctly preserving spaces and so on in arguments). Don't use `$*`, which concatenates the arguments with spaces in between (so that `groovyrun 'foo bar'` would degenerate into `groovyrun 'foo' 'bar'`), and [never leave a variable expansion unquoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).
Regarding `exec`, see [reason for exec in wrapper scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279024/reason-for-exec-in-wrapper-scripts)