# What's the difference between eval and exec?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-builtin

`eval` and `exec` are both built in commands of bash(1) that execute commands.

I also see `exec` has a few options but is that the only difference? What happens to their context?

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/525767/what-does-an-exec-command-do/525788#525788

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279030/5510

Comment: is this question the same as: what is the difference between `eval` and `$(...)`?

Comment: Seems that `eval`, `exec` and `$()` are three different things. Here is an example of the difference between `eval` and `$()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155960/what-is-the-use-of-eval-opam-config-env-or-eval-opam-env-and-their-differen

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`eval` and `exec` are completely different beasts. (Apart from the fact that both will run commands, but so does everything you do in a shell.)

```
$ help exec
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
    Replace the shell with the given command.
```

What `exec cmd` does, is exactly the same as just running `cmd`, except that the current shell is replaced with the command, instead of a separate process being run. Internally, running say `/bin/ls` will call `fork()` to create a child process, and then `exec()` in the child to execute `/bin/ls`. `exec /bin/ls` on the other hand will *not* fork, but just replaces the shell.

Compare:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $$ ; ls -l /proc/self ; echo foo'
7218
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 30 16:49 /proc/self -> 7219
foo
```

with

```
$ bash -c 'echo $$ ; exec ls -l /proc/self ; echo foo'
7217
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 30 16:49 /proc/self -> 7217
```

`echo $$` prints the PID of the shell I started, and listing `/proc/self` gives us the PID of the `ls` that was ran from the shell. Usually, the process IDs are different, but with `exec` the shell and `ls` have the same process ID. Also, the command following `exec` didn't run, since the shell was replaced.

---

On the other hand:

```
$ help eval
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Execute arguments as a shell command.
```

`eval` will run the arguments as a command in the current shell.  In other words `eval foo bar` is the same as just `foo bar`. But variables will be expanded before executing, so we can execute commands saved in shell variables:

```
$ unset bar
$ cmd="bar=foo"
$ eval "$cmd"
$ echo "$bar"
foo
```

It will *not* create a child process, so the variable is set in the current shell. (Of course `eval /bin/ls` will create a child process, the same way a plain old `/bin/ls` would.)

Or we could have a command that outputs shell commands. Running `ssh-agent` starts the agent in the background, and outputs a bunch of variable assignments, which could be set in the current shell and used by child processes (the `ssh` commands you would run). Hence `ssh-agent` can be started with:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

And the current shell will get the variables for other commands to inherit.

---

Of course, if the variable `cmd` happened to contain something like `rm -rf $HOME`, then running `eval "$cmd"` would not be something you'd want to do. Even things like command substitutions inside the string would be processed, so *one should **really** be sure that the input to `eval` is safe before using it.*

Often, it's possible to avoid `eval` and avoid even accidentally mixing code and data in the wrong way.

Comment: More details about usage of eval can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46944004/2079103

Comment: @clearlight, well, that reminds me to add the usual disclaimer about _not using `eval` in the first place_ to this answer too. Stuff like indirectly modifying variables can be done in many shells through `declare`/`typeset`/`nameref` and expansions like `${!var}`, so I would use those instead of `eval` unless I really had to avoid it.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation with focus about some important points. Thank you!

Comment: is this question the same as: what is the difference between `eval` and `$(...)`?

Comment: @CharlieParker, no, the command substitution `$(...)` is a yet another thing, different from `eval` and `exec`. Of course that one, also, runs a command...

Comment: @ilkkachu what is the difference between `$(...)` and `exec`? Sorry trying to figure out what is going on. All these three (`exec`, `eval`, `$(...)`) things seem very similar and I can't figure out the difference. For context I am going through https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash and trying to understand the command `eval $(opam env)`.

Comment: @CharlieParker, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution, I'm not sure if there's a tutorial-like question here on the site.

Answer (score 32):

`exec` does not create a new process.  It *replaces* the current process with the new command.  If you did this on the command line then it will effectively end your shell session (and maybe log you out or close the terminal window!)

e.g.

```
ksh% bash
bash-4.2$ exec /bin/echo hello
hello
ksh%
```

Here I'm in `ksh` (my normal shell).  I start `bash` and then inside bash I `exec /bin/echo`.  We can see that I've been dropped back into `ksh` afterwards because the `bash` process was replace by `/bin/echo`.

Comment: umm on the face dropped back into ksh b/c process was replaced by echo doesnt make that much sense?

Comment: is this question the same as: what is the difference between `eval` and `$(...)`?

Answer (score 19):

#### TL;DR

`exec` is used to replace current shell process with new and handle stream redirection/file descriptors if no command has been specified. `eval` is used to evaluate strings as commands. Both may be used to built up and execute a command with arguments known at run-time, but `exec` replaces process of the current shell in addition to executing commands.

#### exec buil-in

Syntax:

```
exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
```

According to the manual if there is command specified this built-in

> ...replaces the shell.  No new process is created.  The  arguments  become  the arguments  to  command.

In other words, if you were running `bash` with PID 1234 and if you were to run `exec top -u root` within that shell, the `top` command will then have PID 1234 and replace your shell process.

Where is this useful ? In something known as wrapper scripts. Such scripts build up sets of arguments or make certain decisions about what variables to pass into environment, and then use `exec` to replace itself with whatever command is specified, and of course providing those same arguments that the wrapper script has built up along the way.

What the manual also states is that:

> If command is not specified, any redirections  take  effect  in the current shell

This allows us to redirect anything from current shells output streams into a file. This may be useful for logging or filtering purposes, where you don't want to see `stdout` of commands but only `stderr`. For instance, like so:

```
bash-4.3$ exec 3>&1
bash-4.3$ exec > test_redirect.txt
bash-4.3$ date
bash-4.3$ echo "HELLO WORLD"
bash-4.3$ exec >&3
bash-4.3$ cat test_redirect.txt 
2017年 05月 20日 星期六 05:01:51 MDT
HELLO WORLD
```

This behavior makes it handy for [logging in shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/314675/3701431), redirecting streams to separate files or [processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442465/85039), and other [fun stuff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18904/85039) with file descriptors.

On the source code level at least for `bash` version 4.3, the  `exec` built in is defined in `builtins/exec.def`. It parses the received commands, and if there are any, it passes things on to `shell_execve()` function defined in `execute_cmd.c` file.

Long story short, there exists a family of `exec` commands in C programming language, and `shell_execve()` is basically a wrapper function of `execve`:

```
/* Call execve (), handling interpreting shell scripts, and handling
   exec failures. */
int
shell_execve (command, args, env)
     char *command;
     char **args, **env;
{
```

#### eval built-in

The bash 4.3 manual states(emphasis added by me):

> The args are read and concatenated together into a single command.  This command is then read  and  **executed by the shell**, and its exit status is returned as the value of eval.

Note that there is no process replacement occurring. Unlike `exec` where the goal is to simulate `execve()` functionality, the `eval` built in only serves to "evaluate" arguments, just as if the user has typed them on the command line. As such, new processes are created.

Where this might be useful ? As Gilles pointed out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11065196/3701431) , "...eval is not used very often. In some shells, the most common use is to obtain the value of a variable whose name is not known until runtime". Personally, I've used it in couple of scripts on Ubuntu where it was necessary to execute/evaluate a command based on the specific workspace that the user was currently using.

On the source code level, it is defined in `builtins/eval.def` and passes the parsed input string to `evalstring()` function.

Among other things, `eval` can [assign variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442218/85039) which remain in current shell execution environment, while `exec` cannot:

```
$ eval x=42
$ echo $x
42
$ exec x=42
bash: exec: x=42: not found
```

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I've edited that part, thanks, though arguably it does spawn a new process, the PID merely remains the same as of current shell. In future consider editing answers, instead of leaving a comment and downvote , especially where such minor thing as 7-word phrase is in question; it's far less time consuming to edit and correct an answer, and it's far more helpful.

Answer (score 5):

> creating a new child process, run the arguments and returning the exit status.

Uh what?  The whole point of `eval` is that it does not in any way create a child process.  If I do

```
eval "cd /tmp"
```

in a shell, then afterwards the *current* shell will have changed directory.  Neither does `exec` create a new child process, instead it changes the current executable (namely the shell) for the given one; the process id (and open files and other stuff) stay the same.  As opposed to `eval`, an `exec` will not return to the calling shell unless the `exec` itself fails due to being unable to find or load the executable or die to argument expansion problems.

`eval` basically interprets its argument(s) as a string after concatenation, namely it will do an extra layer of wildcard expansion and argument splitting.  `exec` doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: The original question read "eval and exec are both builtin commands of Bash (1) and executes commands, creating a new child process, run the arguments and returning the exit status"; I've edited out the false presumption.

Answer (score 0):

**Evaluation**

These work:

```
$ echo hi
hi

$ eval "echo hi"
hi

$ exec echo hi
hi
```

However, these do not:

```
$ exec "echo hi"
bash: exec: echo hi: not found

$ "echo hi"
bash: echo hi: command not found
```

---

**Process image replacement**

This example demonstrates how `exec` replaces the image of its calling process:

```
# Get PID of current shell
sh$ echo $$
1234

# Enter a subshell with PID 5678
sh$ sh

# Check PID of subshell
sh-subshell$ echo $$
5678

# Run exec
sh-subshell$ exec echo $$
5678

# We are back in our original shell!
sh$ echo $$
1234
```

Notice that `exec echo $$` ran with the PID of the subshell! Furthermore, after it was complete, we were back in our original `sh$` shell.

On the other hand, `eval` does *not* replace the process image. Rather, it runs the given command as you would normally within the shell itself. (Of course, if you run a command that requires a process to be spawned... it does just that!)

```
sh$ echo $$
1234

sh$ sh

sh-subshell$ echo $$
5678

sh-subshell$ eval echo $$
5678

# We are still in the subshell!
sh-subshell$ echo $$
5678
```

Comment: I posted this answer because the other examples didn't really illustrate this in a sufficiently comprehensible way for feeble minds such as I.

Comment: Poor choice of words: Process substitution is [an existing concept](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) that seems to be unrelated to whatever you're illustrating here.

Comment: @muru Is "process replacement" better? I'm not sure what the correct terminology is. The manpage seems to call it "replacing the process image".

Comment: Hmm, dunno. (But when I hear "replacing the process image", I think: `exec`)