# Does running exec do anything?

Tags: exec

Does running `exec` in an interactive shell do anything? I mean simply `exec`, with no parameters whatsoever.

What about in a script?

If it does do something, what does it do?

Comment: You might be interested in reading answers to a related question [What's the difference between eval and exec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366228/85039) They already cover essentially what the two existing answers already did , and then cover extra information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If command  is not specified, any redirections can take effect in the current shell.* This is short version of what man page says .That I understand as  when `exec` is executed empty it does not start a new shell , does not make  changes in the current, and returns code 0 which means it was executed without errors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

## When called with a command as argument.

Normally when you run a command, it calls `fork` and `exec` (plus pipe, etc). But when you add `exec` at the start (e.g. `exec ls`), it does not call `fork`, therefore the shell is replaced by the command. That is the command runs in the same process as the shell was in (the shell no longer exists).

## When called without a command.

It applies redirections, that are then in affect afterward.